# Название команды (окна)

Tags: java

Только изучаю swing. Для воплощения своей задумки требуется окно, которое будет отображать данные, введенные с помощью кнопок. Чтобы конкретнее дать вам понять то, что я хочу: это что-то наподобие калькулятора windows. (Реализацию набора символом с клавиатуры не трогаю пока что). Так как называется это окно\команда?

Comment: этот объект называется JFrame

Comment: Окно сразу должно выводить введенные символы(как в калькуляторе виндовс)

Comment: а вообще рекомендую сначало прочитать книгу Шилдта "Swing для начинающих" и уже потом что то делать свое

Comment: Я понимаю что jframe, но меня конкретно интересует это окно, ведь в jframe много различных команд

Comment: тогда JTextField а вообще смотри сюда https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html

Comment: нет, в данной я сам ввожу текст, а мне нужно с кнопок вводить число, а выводиться оно должно сразу же(еще раз говорю как в калькуляторе виндовс)

Comment: такого не бывает, ты вставляешь кнопку - вешаешь на него листенер который уже заполняет текстовое поле

Comment: Вооооооооооооооооооооооооот это уже мне намного помогло. Спасибо. Закрыли тему

Comment: еще раз - прочти книгу которую я указал выше. она есть на сайте который называть нельзя. и только потому уже изобретай свой велосипед.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно код программы, осуществляющей нечто похожее (создаете класс Main в IDE, копируете туда, нажимаете исполнить - run):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    private int number = 0; //создаем переменную number и присваиваем ей значение 0
    private JLabel label; // создаем ссылку для объектов класса JLabel, лейбл - поле для отображения текста в нашем случае
    private JButton button; // кнопка - тут думаю понятно

    public Main(){
        super("Test frame"); // Устанавливаем имя окна класса Main с помощью конструктора его предка JFrame
        label = new JLabel("Input:" + number); // создаем объект класса Jlabel и сохраняем в переменную label ссылку на него
        button = new JButton("increment"); // аналогично с кнопкой
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout()); //Создаем временные компоненты - панель
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(button); // добавляем кнопку в панель
        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // добавляем панель на окно
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //устанавливаем завершение процесса при закрытии окна
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main frame = new Main(); //создаем экземпляр класса Main
        frame.setVisible(true); //делаем его видимым
        frame.pack(); //устанавливаем оптимальный размер окна
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//устанавливаем позицию окна на экране
        frame.button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //привязываем инстанс класса ActionListener(слушатель действий) к кнопке
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.number+=1; //увеличиваем переменную на 1
                frame.label.setText("Input:" + frame.number); // обновляем наш лейбл
            }
        });
    }
}
```

А теперь по порядку:

1. То что вы хотите реализовать - это не окно и не команда. Это программа, использующая классы стандартных библиотек Java: awt и swing. С их помощью действительно можно реализовать окно на котором будет элемент, отображающий данные, и кнопка, с помощью которой можно эти данные изменять.
2. Что вам нужно знать, чтобы самостоятельно реализовать подобное:

-что такое классы и наследование
-примитивные и ссылочные типы 
-что такое методы
-прочитать про каждый класс использованный в программе выше(подсвечивается голубым цветом)

Короче говоря освоить азы, без них никуда.